# Learning path for web development using Python

Tags: python

No background in programming. I have been managing a development team (Website and Android) for past 2-3 years and I found it very interesting and got a hang of it, the problem solving and analytical thinking stuff. I have even suggested logics to the sr. developers and from that experience, I strongly believe that I can do programming.

interested in Python based web-development. So how to go about it? How to start? Should I only learn front end tools now or go simultaneously? Expecting a detailed learning path. Pls help and guide!!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of python web development courses available on Udemy. With python you can go with Flask, light weight, or Django, full featured. Just look for and pick one that fits with your level of experience.